# How to add “Was this article helpful? Yes/No” in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, survey

How can I add a survey question on a SharePoint 2013 page as shown in the image below?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You want a server side solution or client side solution ?

Comment: I think in my case it would be client side solution. I am new to SharePoint and working on customizing the master page, display templates etc. I don't have access to Visual Studio or Design Manager. The client asked if we can implement this and I tried searching for a solution but couldn't find anything. They want to see if their pages have been useful to the users or not.

Answer (score 0):

If it’s for single page, you could add html to Content Editor web part and trigger client function and then insert data to custom list by JSOM.
For CRUD by JSOM, you could check below thread for reference.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx

If you need add this to multiple page, you have to consider to add the code to page layout/master page.

Comment: Thanks Robert! This looks interesting. Let me give it a try.